# Get name from only date and ID matched with people list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula, vlookup

I have rawdata with only ID's and dates of transactions. Then I have a list of people; their ID, their hire date and their name.

What I want is a column in the rawdata that gives me the persons name. The problem is, that the ID is re-used if the person quits, and another one starts.

Since I have the transaction date, I figure it should be possible to check:

IF the transaction matches the period they were hired, then get the right name.

Is this possible, and then how?

```
Rawdata:
Column A = Transaction date
Column B = ID
Column C = Here I want their name


People list:
Column A = ID
Column B = Name
Column C = Hire date
```

Example (Excel Online - can be edited):
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjWVkb2UBexjhzAKMy-YiE5EoKwc

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: First off, put your computer to sleep and go tell your boss NOT TO REUSE PERSONNEL IDS! If nothing else, there is a chance that the person may come back to work as well as a myriad of other factors that makes this practice JUST PLAIN WRONG. There are more than enough numbers in this universe that new employees can have a unique ID. Think of timecard history identification.

Comment: Wow.. Other than this particular sheet, the reusage of ID's are a practical issue as my company is a small one, and they are connected to licences - I cannot get a new licence each time I hire someone.

Comment: If the licences are not transferable within the company you may be breaking the law by having different employees use them under an alias (e.g. personnel ID).

Comment: Well, I use other ID's which are not connected to this data. However, this is not the topic here. Thanks for the help in the end though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to name your tables *People* and *Raw_Data* to use structured table references in the formula. Additonally, I added some data and changed a few dates.

```
=INDEX(People[Agent Name], AGGREGATE(15,6, (ROW(People[Personal ID])-ROW(People[[#Headers],[Agent Name]]))/((People[Personal ID]=[@[Personal ID]])*(People[Hire date]=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (People[Hire date])/((People[Personal ID]=[@[Personal ID]])*(People[Hire date]<=[@[Transaction date]])), 1))), 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your reference table is ordered in chronological order oldest to newest:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($G$8:INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)))/(($E$8:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))=B8)*($G$8:INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))<A8)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: I unsorted the People data and had to use an inner aggregate to gain the correct results.

Comment: @Jeeped I saw, I did not want to go that deep, or take the time to do so.